# Jackson ObjectNode: how to not include NULL on serialization

Tags: json, scala, null, jackson

I'm having trouble excluding Null/Empty properties when I serialize my ObjectNode back to a string.  I googled around and all the references about *JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL* are regarding serializing and deserializing from a Bean, not an ObjectNode - It seams that the serialization behaves differently from an "arbitrary" ObjectNode instead of a pre-defined Bean.

My goal is to have the output = **{"name":"myName"}**, Not **{"name":"myName","nu":null,"empt":""}**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

val jsonInputStr = """{"name": "myName"}"""
val newObjMapper = new ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)

val json = newObjMapper.readTree(jsonInputStr).asInstanceOf[ObjectNode]
json.put("nu", null.asInstanceOf[String])
json.put("empt", "")
val str = newObjMapper.writeValueAsBytes(json)
println(s"OUTPUT = ${new String(str)}")
```

prints:
**OUTPUT = {"name":"myName","nu":null,"empt":""}**

Answer (score 0):

If you deserialize the JSON into a `Map` instead of a `JsonNode` structure, when you re-serialize the Map, it will obey the serialization inclusion parameters.

*Edit to address comment:*

If you want to use the node structure and don't mind a slight performance hit of doing multiple serialization steps, then you could always do something like:

```
val rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(...)
...
val map = objectMapper.treeToValue(rootNode, Map::class)
val json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map)
```

Comment: A big nested map (my actual Json object is very nested with many different types)?  Yuck.  Was really hoping this feature could work on an ObjectNode or JsonNode and it's just my syntax is wrong.  They've clearly added it for Beans already and the objectMapper is traversing the whole tree node by node, should be easy for them to have provided the feature. ...it seems not many people use the mutable ObjectNode.

Comment: I have edited my answer provide a solution that allows you to do your domain logic on the node (albeit kind of ugly serialization).